# iOS7 : View talking portrait frame when loading child view controller from landscape mode

Tags: ios

I am creating iPad Universal application with UITabBarViewController. When I navigate to First tab screen from Login view while my Login screen is in portrait mode. FirstView controller load properly and rotation work nicely.

But if I rotate device on Landscape mode then doLogin I navigate to First tab View then UI messed up as root view still taking portrait frame.

This however works nicely on iOS 8.
This is how UI looks on iOS 8(Correct UI)

[image]

This is how UI looks on iOS7(incorrect UI)
[image]

Here is my code:

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

FirstViewController *vc = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];

NSArray *viewControllersArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:vc, nil];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllersArray animated:YES];

[self addChildViewController:tabBarController];
[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

I am using this code on LoginViewController. LoginViewController is my RootViewController
In didFinishLaunchWithOption i am setting LoginController as a rootViewcontroller using below 
code:
      [self.window setRootViewController:self.loginviewController];

Comment: Hey,

Got the exact same problem
App looks amazing on iOS8 but a total mess on iOS7.

did you find a solution?

CHeers

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem too, I'm adding my view to a landscape nav controller but the view frame size is portrait. I don't know if there is a better way around this than what i ended up doing, but this was my solution.

I put the following in the viewDidLoad of the view controller thats being added.

```
// Hack because iOS 7 was loading in portrait instead of landscape
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 8)
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width);
```